# express deprecated res.send(status, body): Use res.status(status).send(body) instead

Tags: express

is anything I am doing wrong because I am new to this, I got **express deprecated res.send(status, body): Use res.status(status).send(body) instead** error when I carry out the update operation using PUT in postman.

```
router.put("/admin/update_profile/:id", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const id = req.params.id;
    const updatedData = req.body;
    const options = { new: true };

    const result = await SomeModel.findByIdAndUpdate(id, updatedData, options);

    res.send(result);
    // res.status(200).send(result)
  } catch (err) {
    res.send("Error ", err);
    // res.status(404).send("Error ", err)
  }
});
```

[image: error snap]

Answer (score 0):

Pretty Much what the error says. Express has deprecated `res.send(status, body);`.
Replace that line with `res.status(status).send(body);`

Please note that writing only `res.send(body);` will send a status of 200 by default, so remember to use `.status()` in failure cases.

Comment: but how to use that, when I replace `res.status(status).send(body);` with that line it will give the same error

Comment: Hello @sumanth, express `.send()` accepts only one argument. In your code you are doing `.send("Error: ", error);`. That makes it two arguments. Please make it like so: `.send(error);` and that error will go away.

Answer (score 0):

> ```js
> res.send("Error ", err);
> ```

You're passing two parameters to `res.send()` which as the warning message indicates is deprecated but still supported.

It's interpreting the string literal `"Error "` as a response status code which is not valid.

You should only pass a single parameter to `send()` and set the status via `status()`

```js
res.status(500).send(err);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
router.put("/admin/update_profile/:id", async (req, res) => {
try {
   const id = req.params.id;
   const updatedData = req.body;
   const options = { new: true };

   const result = await SomeModel.findByIdAndUpdate(id.trim(), updatedData, 
   options);

     res.status(200).send(result);

 } catch (err) {
       res.status(404).send(err);
 }
});
```

Comment: Sounds like you're incorrectly sending a newline or space at the end of your URL in Postman. This isn't something that you should need to deal with server-side, it's a client-side problem only